# TypeScript, moment and ReSharper. "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, resharper, momentjs

I am building a SPA using React + TypeScript + NPM for package management, then Webpack for compiling and bundling.

I am using moment for date conversion and localisation, and I have everything working with the following code;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as moment from 'moment';

class DateFilter extends React.Component<{ value: Date }, {}>{

    render(){
        const { value } = this.props;
        return (
            <time>{ moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }</time>
        );
    }
}
```

All works as expected, however when Resharper is switched on, it gives me an error: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature`

[image]

I have gone through various blog posts/questions and all suggest this is the correct way of importing moment.

My package.json contains...

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
}
```

My tsconfig.json looks like;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "Scripts",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/scripts",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "App/*": [ "App/*" ],
      "Utility/*": [ "Utility/*" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

If I run webpack then everything works fine and there are no errors. Moment works as it should, but it is just Resharper that is freaking out.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @SOK At the point I never found a solution, so moved all reference to moment into a couple of files and added some helper methods. Then just excluded these files from Resharper!